# Kendo tooltip on button with icon doesn't apper corectly on Chrome

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, button, kendo-ui, icons

I have an issue with Kendos tooltips on Goole Chrome. I need to add tooltip on button which have an icon, but when i hover on the icon the tooltip won't appear. When i hover somewhere between the icon it works, but I need tooltip on whole button. I meeting this problem only on Chrome, on IE or Firefox its works fine.. I trying something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Tooltip } from '@progress/kendo-react-tooltip';
import { Button } from "@progress/kendo-react-buttons";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let tooltip = null;

    return (
        <div>
             <div
               onMouseOver={event => tooltip && tooltip.handleMouseOver(event)}
               onMouseLeave={event => tooltip && tooltip.handleMouseLeave(event)}
             >
              <Button 
               className="k-button"
               title="Tooltip message"
               icon="paste"></Button>
               <Tooltip ref={(el) => tooltip = el} anchorElement="target" position="right" />
           </div>
       </div>
       );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
<App />, document.querySelector('my-app'));
```

I also tried use html "button" instead of Kendo "Button", but with the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occurs because the icon is placed inside a span element which does not have a title. By default in Chrome, if an element does not have a title, but its parent does, the browser will show the tooltip. This will come to the KendoReact Tooltip as well:

[enter link description here](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-react/issues/161)

А current option is to set a title to the icon as well:

```
componentDidMount() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('k-i-paste')[0].setAttribute('title', "Tooltip message")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to this one, but I'd thought I'd answer as I've got another way. Seeing as the button handles the click event, the pointer-events can be taken off of the span, and then the tooltip displays no matter where you hover on the button.

I added this to my App.scss file.

```
.k-button > .k-icon {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure your purpose for the `ref` etc...

But this has worked for me, without the `ref`

`anchorElement="target"`

[image]

Of course, the `onClick` and the `{siteName}` are not included but you could use that as an example.  Hope it helps